# How to replace variable with power?

Tags: replacement

I would like to replace variable with power. For example,

```
x^6 /. x^4 -> a + b
```

which I supposed to get $x^2(a+b)$ but I get $x^6$ and I can't use

```
x^6 /. x -> Sqrt[Sqrt[a + b]]
```

because I want to replace $x^4$ only.

Comment: `Last@PolynomialReduce[x^6, {x^4 - a - b}, x]` seems to work on this very specific problem.  It's unlikely you will get a replacement rule to work, since they don't break things down algebraically (into `x^4 * x^2`, for example).  They work on literal matches to patterns.

Comment: @MichaelE2 If this question is more complicate, for example, we change $x^4->a+b$ to $x^4->x^2+a+b$, how to deal with this one?

Comment: I don't understand: if you want to "replace $x^4$ only," as you state, then `x^6` doesn't match what you want, and the answer you get is correct (no replacement happens).

Comment: x^6 /. x^n_ :> (a+b)^Quotient[n,4]* x^Mod[n,4] gives you  x^2* (a+b)

Comment: @Jens I mean only $x^4$ not lower than that. I might use the wrong word.

Comment: @Bill Your suggestion works!!! Thanks.

Comment: My 5 cents to this beautiful question: `rule = x^n_ /; n >= 4 && n \[Element] Integers -> x^(n - 4)*(a + b);` and then  `x^6 /. rule` gives `(a + b) x^2`. But what would you like to do with `x^8 /. rule` giving `(a + b) x^4`?

Comment: But I have no idea what generalizations to this very specific problem you have in mind. What's wrong with `Last@PolynomialReduce[x^6, {x^4 - x^2 - a - b}, x]`? After one reduction you have `x^2 (x^2+a+b)`, which has an `x^4` that needs (?) reducing, which the code does. -- Actually, `PolynomialRemainder[x^6, x^4 - x^2 - a - b, x]` is simpler.

Comment: Hi Cho, Don't forget to upvote good answers (and other people's questions) using the triangle above the number next to the post, and use the checkmark to "accept" the answer to your question that you think best answers it.

Comment: @QuantumDot Thanks for your suggestion. I think Bill's comment is perfectly solve my problem and I've already vote for his comment. Next time I will be more careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Bill's comment above the following use of [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) ensures that multiples of exponent 4 are properly substituted all the time:

```
f[x_] := a + b + x^2;
x /: Power[x, n_?(Quotient[#, 4] >= 1 &)] := x^Mod[n, 4] f[x]^Quotient[n, 4]
Table[{i, x^i}, {i, 15}] // TableForm
```

[image]

If we [`Expand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expand.html), the substitution works as well:

```
Expand[x^3 (a + b + x^2)] (* a x^3 + b x^3 + x^5 *)
(* a x^3 + b x^3 + x (a + b + x^2) *)
```