# Mathematica syntax

Tags: programming, mathematica-online

Please I'mm trying to understand this sentence in *Mathematica* if $d=(x4+34x3+45)y^4$
; my task to replace all `y2y2` by `x3+2x+2x3+2x+2` some suggest to me to use this line

```
d=d/.y^u_ :->(x^3+2x+2)^(u/2) /; EvenQ[u]
```

Can any one explain this line and thank you in advance.

Comment: it needs to replace all $y^2$ by $x^3+2x+2$

Comment: See also [How to replace variable with power?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131359/how-to-replace-variable-with-power)

Comment: You can search the documentation for the special character combinations you see but don't understand, e.g. `/.` and `/;`. Their `FullForm` names are `ReplaceAll` and `Condition` respectively.

Comment: note you have a syntax error. the sequence `:->` should just be `:>`. (  It may also appear as a colon followed by a special arrow character, but not the three character sequence you have there )

Comment: @george2079 i agree with you and this what makes me ask about its meaning 
what is the difference between  :> and -> 
what is the meaning of y^u_
i need to know the meaning of y^u_

Answer (score 3):

```
d = (x^4 + 34 x^3 + 45) y^4 
d /. y^u_ :> (x^3 + 2 x + 2)^(u/2) /; EvenQ[u]
```

[image]

picking this apart, `/. y^u_` says replace every sub expression matching the pattern `y` to an exponent, where the exponent can be anything. Whatever the exponent is, gets named `u`.  As a subtlety there must be an explicit exponent, ie. `y` by itself is not recognized as `y^1`

All the way to the right the `/; EvenQ[u]` is a `Conditional` that says only apply this rule if `u` is even.

The `:>` is a `RuleDelayed` , replace `y^u` with the following expression using the specific value of `u` at the time of the replacement.  In this example the delayed rule is actually not needed. You will get the same if you use a regular rule: `->`

For your very specific example you could have just done more simply

```
d /. y^4 -> (x^3 + 2 x + 2)^2
```

Comment: Really you are amazing  nice and helpful explanation and clarifications , thank you very much